# Parallax technique on the Web: Types and Best-practices

Tags: scrolling, parallax

I'm trying to gather some best-practices on how to use the **[parallax effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallax)**, combined with different types of uses of the technique.

Here is my beginning, do you know more than me? (probably!) What am I missing? What do you think is important to consider when using the parallax technique.

#### **UX best-practices**

- Good story line.
- One message per state/page.
- Navigation between states is clear.
- Persistent navigation that indicates position.
- *Play* is encouraged by providing a scrubber-mechanism that lets the user go back and forth between stages.
- *Mobile first* is honored and how/if it ports to smaller screens.

#### **Types of uses + Example**

- good story - [hobolobo.net](http://hobolobo.net/)
- vertical parallax - [nikebetterworld.com](http://www.nikebetterworld.com)
- horizontal parallax - [yessbmx.com](http://yessbmx.com)
- animation/frames - [beetle.de/full](http://beetle.de/full)
- 3d rooms - [ajaxian.com/archives/3dcss](http://www.ajaxian.com/archives/3dcss)
- worlds / 2-axis parallax - [http://www.mauriciostudio.com](http://mauriciostudio.com)

#### Further considerations:

- Know why you use the technique, it won't work for most sites. Just like any design pattern, give it some thought.
- Animation/frame type uses of the technique are often laggy ([example](http://beetle.de/full)) and don't port well across devices or slower computers.
- It doesn't have to work across the entire screen and involve all elements but can be done more subtly (example: [1](http://www.rowtothepole.com/)).

Comment: In HCI at least it's commonly accepted that 3D displays are largely inferior in presenting information (https://wikispaces.psu.edu/display/331Grp1/Navigation+3D+vs.+2D+HCI+Information). The only exception I would make is when the information _is_ 3D (video game or movie) or the information is so _complex_ information must be presented in 3D (scientific information often falls into this category)

Comment: FYI: Another example at [Legoland Discovery Centre](http://www.legolanddiscoverycentre.co.uk/manchester/en/index.htm)

Comment: @RogerAttrill: Great example of how to use the technique. +1

Comment: @BenBrocka: I assume you are only talking about the 3D uses of this technique (link was broken). It's not really about 3D as much as it is moving element juxtaposed from each other to create a more immersive experience.

Comment: @WmasterJ Weird, here's one of the more important sources http://www.useit.com/alertbox/981115.html . It's about 3D techniques in general, and paralax is inherently a 3D effect even if individual items are 3D. It can look good but it's not helpful to digest info. If that's not your point of course it's not as relevant

Comment: @BenBrocka: I totally agree with you about actual 3D, but I don't think it applies to this as a topic only a small subset of ways people use it. If you look at some examples, such as: http://www.rowtothepole.com/ and  http://silverbackapp.com or even http://www.nikebetterworld.com/ they all use this technique in a way that doesn't resemble actual 3D rendering at all but it still gives more dimension and play to the users experience.

Comment: Definition check: I don't think it's parallax unless you have more than one layer moving in concert at proportional rates.  For example, if you have a single foreground layer moving on top of a static background layer, that's just 2D animation.  If the background moves slightly in proportion to how the foreground moves, you've got parallax, yes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think "parallax" is a novel UX *pattern* to be taxonomized as such. It's a dynamic visual effect applied to other (ancient!) scroll, pan or carousel interfaces.  Your bullet points apply to these patterns more than the 3D-ish effect.

Another way to put this is that the illusion of depth or moving through space is part of the transitioning between states that occurs all the time.

That said, I do think this is an interesting topic, and in the right context - generally a *guided tour* kind of use case? - could increase interest and engagement in a scroll/pan/carousel interface.

An interesting way to look at this is not to be so focused on the parallax effect but to look at this as UI that employs any spatial distortion techniques.  For example, this [bling-y portfolio site](http://onedesigncompany.com/) doesn't look 3d, but it feels like you are *progressing* because of the transition effects.

Comment: Agree, and the link you sent actually uses a parallax affect similarly to the nike one for their Work space :)   Back toy our first point (not a novel UX pattern), that is the reason I posted the Wikipedia link so that people can get an understanding what the origins are.

Comment: Yes, and for the record I am totally in agreement that there are UX considerations to applying these effects.  I wonder, though, if your "UX Best Practices" are really aimed at the underlying scroll/pan/carousel patterns, and don't have to do with the new visual depth.  Another way to look at it - if you removed the depth illusion in all of these sites, wouldn't you still want to follow the same UX guidelines?

Comment: Oh, I wouldn't call that parallax - it's just literally one layer moving on top of a background (that doesn't move).  The appearance is very 2D.  I think you might need a another layer or two (moving _proportionally_ to the top layer) before you can call it parallax.

Comment: Agree and agree to both of these things. I now think what the parallax effect does is simply add more detail and new possibilities to animate or visually improve the experience. When we look at it like this there are other things to consider for the parallax effect that focuses on how to use these different layers to communicate something that would otherwise not be possible.

Answer (score 3):

Why, oh why, would you want to do that?  Please don't do that...

The sites that you linked may have "cool and interesting" UI's but the UX was terrible.  If I wasn't specifically trying to work out what you were thinking of doing I would have left each of them  very quickly.

**Clarity first**.

(And remember that the UX gods get very upset when people don't follow their first commandment, and may choose to smite thee with a plague of confused customers)

**Edit:** I am answering this specifically for web sites as those are the examples given.

Comment: "cool and interesting" sounds like a great UX to me. Perhaps you mean the *UI* was terrible?

Comment: The Nike site was great, you could either scroll of click the circle navigation on the right site, which also gave page content on hover. Very clever site and a great UX.

Comment: "Clarity first" doesn't always fit the goals of a site.  Many a marketing person would say *emotion first*.

Comment: @Rahul: good point.  Corrected.

Comment: @MattRockwell: I spent some time on the site and I never even noticed the navigation on the right.  How many other people do you think will miss it?

Comment: @JohnGB I'm not sure, but when it's one of two things you can do (the other being scroll), the limited options almost force you to see it. It changes as you scroll to, so it's easy to see the movement, even though it's against other movement in the background. But even still, if you can't see it, then the only thing you can do is scroll, which is incredibly straightforward.

Comment: And on the initial page (top) the nav appears next to the guys hand, which your eye naturally goes to with the nature of that image.

Comment: I just checked out the mobile version also. It's even simpler, no parallax, just scrolling and the nav is gone altogether. It's as simple as it gets.

Comment: I closed two of them waiting for them to finish loading: too many assets or too much imagery. The Nike one, I scrolled a little bit figured out that there was nothing to justify the work to scroll and closed it. Don't.

Comment: @JohnGB - I agree with what you are saying, "cool and interesting" don't interest me. Anything we design needs to fit the purpose. Most of them are simply examples, the Nike one is the only really good one. I'll try to swap the others out for better examples as I find them.

Comment: @JohnGB - From this answer I take: "Know why you use the technique, it won't work for most sites. Just like any design pattern, give it some thought."

Answer (score 3):

One of the first questions you need to ask is "what benefit does this provide?" In this case, I am unconvinced that it provides a lot. Yes, it is cool as a concept, and there are some situations where it would be appropriate - in particular, where it matched other marketing aspects for the brand.

However, as an interface to interact with, it is not clear or easy. Some of them were just confusing, and others gave no indication what I should do ( and this is an important aspect of any UI ).

So use it only if there is a good marketing reason for it, but otherwise, concentrate on letting users interact nicely, and not gimmicks.

Comment: I think we are totally on the same side. I didn't provide the best examples above and I'm trying to swap them out so that others who come here later will be able to get some got inspiration that also works as examples for how it could be done. I think in general the question of benefit needs to be asked with any UI design pattern, but with these ones even more so! I do feel like it isn't tied directly to marketing, it could also simple be something that ever so slightly enhances the experience

Answer (score 1):

I think this can be made a community wiki post just by an answerer checking the 'community wiki' box below the reply field. I'll give that a go. (*/EDIT - Nope, that just converts this answer to be a Wiki post. Not sure how to convert the question to a wiki one though)*.

However, in order for this answer to be more relevant to the question I will make one observation about the set of links featured above:

The 3D Rooms example can probably serve a purpose out in the 'real world' (i.e. not just in developer portfolio pages or tech demos as the other links really are). Because it exists as a seperate content-element it can be used to complement the existing content of the page it sits on (such as for a product demo on an ecommerce site) whereas for the other examples in the list the parallax feature *IS* the site; it's not a complementary feature. Those sites appear to be just an updated version of the old 100%-built-in-Flash sites that we used to see many years ago, with all the drawbacks that those sites had (low searchability, accessibility etc).

Answer (score 1):

As for where the technique is used as part of the UX the primary example would be side-scrolling video games. In that context, it makes perfect sense...it gives the experience of 3D without the distraction. It's still a 2D interaction plane, just made more interesting (and potentially performant in the earlier days) by using the technique.

As for other places it makes sense to use it, that's a tough one. I see it on occasion on web sites that are designed to encourage exploration...often a trendy ad agency site that decides to try a side-scrolling flash based site. They were neat for a while. Not sure they really impress folks much anymore.

Comment: I totally agree with the exploration part of it. I believe it speakes to a more emotional part of us that appreciates these exploratory UI's. But the trade-off is of course that there needs to be a balance between utility and play.

Comment: I agree. There is definitely places and times where a more exploratory-focused UI makes a lot of sense. I'm thinking educational type sites or rich story based sites.